# Chamar outra página com botão bootstrap não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html

Esse javascript bem simples, não funciona:

```
function Nova() {
            location.href = 'pme_beneficiarios.html';
        }
```

Essa é a chamada no botão:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-task" onclick="Nova();">Beneficiário</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar o window:

```
function Nova() {
        window.location.href = 'pme_beneficiarios.html';
}
```